# How to release clipping masks on Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, clipping-mask

I'm having trouble to find where do I release a clipping mask on Illustrator.
I want to release it to make another mask, but when I select the object which is "equipped" with the mask, it only selects the mask vector, not the objects.
Is there a way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also control clipping masks in the **Transparency Panel** :

[image]

[image]

***Note:***
 If the Transparency Panel isn't in the workspace, it can be found under
 **Window > Transparency** or accessed by the keyboard shortcut `Command + Shift + F10`

Answer (score 0):

Oh, nevermind. Just **right-click** the clipped object and then click on **Release Clipping Mask**.